# Is there any software for mac to create this particular 3d histogram?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, graph

Is there any software for mac to create this particular 3d histogram: 
[image: 3d histogram]
given a matrix of value?

I've tried with Numbers but it doesn't have 3d histograms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do things like that in [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) or the free clone [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html). There's a script [here](http://daily-notes.net/2011/02/17/matlab-3d-histogram-and-surface-plot/).

Comment: I see.. but you know, Matlab is though to install and then I've to code.. it is a bit though solution. I have a table in excel/Numbers with these values, it would be great to just copy paste this table and generate the graph...

Comment: @Patrick Of course, I was surprised that I couldn't find something in a quick google search. But I guess diagrams like this aren't mainstream enough for specialised software, so you have to use mathematics stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is able to do this.

Comment: Any tiny software doing that by just adding values to a table ?

Answer (score 1):

[Grapher](http://guides.macrumors.com/Grapher) is probably the app you are looking for. It is already installed on your Mac by default.

Comment: Uhm, the software you suggest is more for draw analytical functions... etc in 2D and 3D. I don't see the option to draw histograms given a set of values.

Comment: @romeovs I might be wrong but I can't see 3d histograms in Gnuplot as well.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot mught be ablo to do this. I've seen pictures where something like this is done:

[image: hist example]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Excel works for this sort of graph as well.

Answer (score 0):

[R Studio](http://rstudio.org/) (the wonderful IDE for [R](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)) can do this. It's the kind of the thing it was meant to do really. Free, open source and, IMO, easier to grasp than Octave (and free, wherease Matlab is most definitely not). You'll likely want the [RGL addon](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/students/peter_cock/r/3d_bar_chart) to do a 3D plot.

[There's a StackOverflow question that deals with how you go about plotting the 3D histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405575/how-does-one-plot-a-3d-stacked-histogram-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice](http://libreoffice.org/) (~ [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) ~ [NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org)) to give some free office applications.